# OAUTH Login Security

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I have a webapi which uses OAUTH for token-based authentication. All the API calls are using tokens with the exception of the initial login. The login call appears to pass the username and password in plain text. Using Fiddler I can see exactly what my password is. Is there a way to encrypt the username and password so someone can't get a user's password or is this okay as is?

Comment: Normally that's handled by using HTTPS

Comment: I tried that but I can still see it in Fiddler. Am I worried over nothing?

Comment: Fiddler can intercept your traffic by -> https://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp if you're not sure if that's what's happening then try using wireshark and see if you can still see it.

Comment: @JimW Yeah, I did that. Even with the Login going over HTTPS you can still see the username and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is being downvoted (because StackOverflow reasons) I'll try to answer this myself as no one else wants to. It doesn't look like this matters. I checked with a few other websites, including banks, and they all do the same thing. You don't need to encrypt a username and password before sending it to an API.

Comment: @BobKaufman Did you not see my reply to Jim's comment? Even with HTTPS you can still see the username and password in plain text via Fiddler.